# Look for Assistance With Text Overflow/Linear Gradient in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am trying to create my first website from scratch using HTML/CSS. The problem I am having is that text I have on a page exceeds the bounds of the background image and when I scroll downwards, the container (.violence) seems to stop displaying the linear-gradient and moves on to a white background. Is there any way I can extend and fit the gradient to match the amount of text I put in?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried searching the web for solutions but my lack of knowledge and understanding of HTML/CSS have prevented me from resolving the issue.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(background.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.welcome {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 375px;
  margin-top: 425px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.violence {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 375px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h4 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

h5 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h6 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h7 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h8 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h9 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trajan Pro", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Quest for Arrakis: The Second Imperial Renaissance</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
      </div>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="home.html"> HOME </a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="setting.html"> GAME SETTING </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> CHARACTERS AND ENTITIES </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> WRITING SAMPLES </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> GAME FEATURES </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> JOIN </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> CONTACT US </a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="violence">
      <h3>
        <p>"There is no escape—we pay for the violence of our ancestors." <br>- Frank Herbert, Dune</p>
      </h3>
      <h4>
        <p>Quest for Arrakis II continues the decade long history and political machinations of the original Quest for Arrakis. It is an intense setting that stays true to the canon as set forth by Frank Herbert and focuses primarily on power politics and
          grand story telling. Much like the in the novels most anything is possible…if the player is willing to pay the right price.</p><br>
        <p>The setting is an alternative universe to the world as designed by Frank Herbert and taking place some twelve centuries before the time of Paul Atreides. The Corrino Empire has suffered through a devastating war which has taken the life of the
          previous Emperor and plunged the human race into a period of economic collapse and massive social unrest. Old houses have fallen or been reduced in power leaving a vacuum for the ambitious to make a name for themselves. Under the watchful eye
          of a new soverign the Empire begins the long road back to prosperity. New houses seek to establish themselves as old ones try to return to glory.</p><br>
        <p>We offer an intense gaming atmosphere with motivated players, helpful staff and well detailed game environment. Everything is story driven and the opportunities are endless for writers willing to be active. Will you raise your banner in this brave
          new age? The perils are daunting and the road will be hard but do you have what it takes to rise to power in the Quest for Arrakis II?</p>
        <h5><br>
          <p>"Beginnings are such delicate times." <br>-Princess Irulan</p>
        </h5>
        <h6><br>
          <p>In the Year 8760 A.G., The Imperium has emerged from a devestating conflict known as The Second Muadru Incursion. Houses have fallen, and widespread economic collapse have devastated the fortunes of the Houses of the Imperium. As the Empire
            returns to glory beneath the Rule of Padishah-Emperor Ezhar the Seventh, Houses New and Old seek to stablise themselves in a turbulent epoch of Imperial History with plenty of opportunity to do so.</p>
        </h6>
        <h7><br>
          <p>"Control the coinage and the courts - let the rabble have the rest." Thus the Padishah Emperor advises you. And he tells you; "If you want profits, you must rule." There is truth in these words, but I ask myself: "Who are the rabble and who
            are the ruled?"<br>-Princess Irulan</p>
        </h7>
        <h8>
          <p><br>The Quest for Arrakis II offers many paths to power.</p>
          <p><br>The Landsraad acts as the Political Hub of the Imperium with the Houses and Players generating most of our Game's Laws and Rule Sets.</p>
          <p><br>If economics piques your interest, then CHOAM serves as the legislature that defines the economic fortunes of the Empire with its Board of Directors governing In Character Policy.</p>
          <p><br>If it is the Favour of the Corrino that drives your ambitions, then the Court of the Emperor will provide you with the opportunity to make a name and reputation for yourself beneath the watchful eye of the Emperor.
            <p><br>Regardless of the path you choose, all roads leads to Arrakis and the fortunes that lie hidden beneath its sands, guarded by Fremen and Worm alike. The journey will not be easy but with enough patience, perseverance and determination,
              you may one day rule the Desert Planet and harness the riches and power for yourself!</p>
        </h8>
        <h9>
          <p><br>"One must always keep the tools of statecraft sharp and ready. Power and fear –sharp and ready." <br>- Baron Vladimir Harkonnen</p>
        </h9>

    </div>

  </header>


</body>

</html>
```

I expect the text to continue being visible.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Redeye. You also need to add the HTML associated with the above CSS - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Apologies! Original post updated.

Comment: sorry buddy i spend more than 30 min trying to understand what is your issue but coudnt know what you want exactly ... like @Nimsrules said you have to privide a MRE (minimal reproducible example) so devs cant resolve your issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question was too vague but I still tried so here is my answer for you.You should apply the background-image property to the violence class itself instead of the header class.

I understand you are new to HTML/CSS but you should check on the web for quality resources to learn the languages as well as best practises.Your code has very basic errors which should not be there.

1. HTML has heading tags `<h1>` to `<h6>` but you have used headings tags beyond that which HTML does not recognise or support.
2. From what I can see you have used headings tags for styling purposes which is wrong.In this case you should remove all the heading tags except `<h3>` which is actually used as a heading.
3. I can also see your knowledge about semantic tags is shallow so it would be better if you spend a little time reading about them.